# Travis CI Execution failed for task ':compileJava'. > invalid source release: 1.8

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

I am getting a random error while trying to get Travis to Build my gradle project.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>
> > invalid source release: 1.8

https://travis-ci.org/WPIRoboticsProjects/grip/builds/77586600

Comment: Your link directs to "The repository at WPIRoboticsProjects/grip was not found." What does your build.gradle file look like? What version of Gradle are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell travis to use java 1.8.
http://blog.travis-ci.com/2013-11-26-test-your-java-libraries-on-java-8/